# Exclude a column from Seaborn Heatmap formatting, but keep in the map

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

So my table looks kinda like this:

```
Cl1  Cl2  Cl3  Sum
0.7  0.9  0.9  2.5
0.8  1.5  0.9  3.2
2.4  2.8  2.1  7.3
```

I want the heatmap color apply to columns 1-3, but not to `Sum`, because it takes all the juice from the heatmap and makes the columns look bland.

All I came up with right now is dividing the Sum value by 100, but that will confuse readers and will require explanations.

Is there a way to not format the Sum column, but keep its values as is?

Some code to get going:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns='Cl1 Cl2 Cl3'.split())

df['Sum'] = 0
for i in df.index:
    df['Sum'].iloc[i] = np.sum(df.iloc[i])

sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, cmap='Reds')
```

Comment: You'll get quicker responses if you post a usable piece of code we can start working with.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon ok, give me a sec, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use mask and add text for the masked zone using for loop.

```
mask = np.zeros((3, 4))
mask[:,3] = True
ax = sns.heatmap(df, mask=mask, annot=True,
             vmin=df.values[:,:3].ravel().min(),
             vmax=df.values[:,:3].ravel().max(),
             annot_kws={"size": 20, "color":"g"})


for (j,i), label in np.ndenumerate(df.values):
    if i == 3:
        ax.text(i+0.5, j+0.5, label, 
                fontdict=dict(ha='center',  va='center',
                                         color='g', fontsize=20))
```

[image]

---

Alternative proposal for replacing the loop:

```
mask = np.zeros((3, 4))
mask[:,3] = True
sns.heatmap(df, mask=mask)
sns.heatmap(df, alpha=0, cbar=False, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 20, "color":"g"})
```

leads to the same result

Comment: To get rid of the loop you might consider my edit at the end.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti Hmm, could you please explain in more detail? Because I tested exactly the above code, with initially imported `numpy`, `seaborn` and `pandas` of course, and it resulted in the same figure you posted before.

Comment: yes it is working, thanks for the edit, way easier than using for loops, I missed that there are two sns.heatmaps!! thanks alot. regards, @SpghttCd

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is simply to see what this looks like in a notebook, you might be able to get by with pandas styling:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import io

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""Cl1  Cl2  Cl3  Sum
0.7  0.9  0.9  2.5
0.8  1.5  0.9  3.2
2.4  2.8  2.1  7.3"""))


cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)

df.style.background_gradient(subset=['Cl1', 'Cl2', 'Cl3'], 
                             low=0, high=3, cmap=cm)
```

Result:

[image: Styled dataframe]

Comment: Thanks for the simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

To complement @SpghttCd's suggestion above, which only plots text in green, instead of the usual colors you'd have (black or white depending on the background color), here's how to do it:

```py
mask = np.zeros((3, 4))
mask[:,3] = True
# Plot just the colors, and the colorbar, masking the non-colored columns.
sns.heatmap(df, mask=mask)
# Plot the values for all colored columns
sns.heatmap(df, alpha=0.0, cbar=False, annot=True, mask=mask)
# Plot the values for non-colored columns (in black)
sns.heatmap(df, alpha=0.0, cbar=False, annot=True, mask=np.logical_not(mask), annot_kws={"color":"k"})
```

This gives this, which you can see, preserves the text color for cells with background color, and sets it to black for cells without background color (otherwise it would plot white text on white).

[image]

You can also do it with logarithmic color map:

```py
mask = np.zeros((3, 4))
mask[:,3] = True
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
# Plot just the colors in logNorm, and the colorbar, masking the non-colored columns.
sns.heatmap(df, norm=LogNorm(), mask=mask)
# Plot the values for all colored columns
sns.heatmap(df, norm=LogNorm(), alpha=0.0, cbar=False, annot=True, mask=mask)
# Plot the values for non-colored columns (in black)
sns.heatmap(df, norm=LogNorm(), alpha=0.0, cbar=False, annot=True, mask=np.logical_not(mask), annot_kws={"color":"k"})
```

[image]